# Clustering dataframe after concatenation of x and y

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have  x and y arrays, x consists of three arrays and y consists of three arrays that consist of seven values

```
x= [np.array([6.03437288]), np.array([6.39850922]), np.array([6.07835145])]
y= [np.array([[-1.06565856, -0.16222044,  7.85850477, -2.62498475, -0.46315498,
        -0.33087472, -0.1394244 ]]), 
    np.array([[-1.41487104e+00,  5.81421750e-03,  7.92917001e+00,
        -3.37987517e+00,  1.14685839e-01, -2.91779263e-01,
         2.51753851e-01]]), 
    np.array([[-1.56496814,  0.2612637 ,  7.60577761, -3.55727614,  0.18844392,
        -0.75112678, -0.48055978]])]
```

I concatenate x and y into one dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,'y': y})
```

then I tried to cluster this dataframe by k-medoids

```
kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(df)
cluster_labels = kmedoids.predict(df)
```

but I faced this error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I tried to search for a solution to this problem, haven't found a concrete solution. any suggestions even with modified the code

Comment: How many dimensions has single point in the dataset to cluster?

Comment: @ ipj dataframe  has two columns, first one x and second one y, y consist of 7 values as you can see in the example , so data point has two arrays (x with one values and y with 7 arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given arrays `x` and `y` as provided in question:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,'y': y})
```

First concatenate `x` and `y` of dataframe into one array per row:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda r: np.append(r.x, r.y), axis = 1)
```

Then create one `X` array:

```
X = np.array(df2.values.tolist())
```

that can be passed to clustering method:

```
kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)
cluster_labels = kmedoids.predict(X)
```

result of clustering:

```
array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: thank a lot for your help, i faced only one problem     Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional ..... i  soved by  X=X.reshape(-1, 1), is that correct ??

Comment: I didn't encounter this error, so hard to say from my perspective.